# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using gwt

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, jsonp, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm building a HTML5 GWT Java game in LibGDX framework where I'm having trouble importing some libs. I'm working in IntelliJ and using Gradle to manage all of my dependencies. I'm not a regular Gradle user, but I tried to make an import to the root build.gradle file like this:

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"
dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-user', version: '2.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-codeserver', version: '2.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-dev', version: '2.6.0'
}
}
```

Therefore I refreshed all Gradle projects in Intellij and builded the project with the command: "gradlew desktop:run". Which works without any compilation error. 
But I get a run time error when I try to run my code where I try to do a GET request to a local server to get the game high score list. 
The code looks like this:

```
package com.sam.reflux.Rest;

import com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public class Request {
private String url = "localhost:9000/highscore";
public void getHighscore(){
    JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
    jsonp.requestString(url, new AsyncCallback<String>() { // <- The error points at this row
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {}

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {}
    });
}
}
```

With following error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequest.getOrCreateCallbacksObject()Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequest.getOrCreateCallbacksObject()Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;
at com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequest.getOrCreateCallbacksObject(Native Method)
at com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequest.<clinit>(JsonpRequest.java:43)
at com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequestBuilder.send(JsonpRequestBuilder.java:205)
at com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequestBuilder.requestString(JsonpRequestBuilder.java:154)
at com.sam.reflux.Rest.Request.getHighscore(Request.java:10)
```

I've tried to google around for "UnsatisfiedLinkError" but I can't find any good answers for it. Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong in my import?

Answer (score 0):

remove these three dependencies from core project these are the part of html module.

```
compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-user', version: '2.6.0'
compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-codeserver', version: '2.6.0'
compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-dev', version: '2.6.0'
```